# Will a laptop with a PCI-E Gen3x 4 SSD slot make any kind of SSD (even non-PCI-E ones) faster than a laptop without such an SSD slot?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

Will a PCI-E slot will speed up any kind of SSD (SATA, m.2 etc.)?

If I put a PCIe SSD inside a regular M.2 SSD slot, will I reap the speed of a PCIe SSD? Or would it be slower than if I put the PCIe SSD in a PCIe slot?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Are you asking what interface is faster,  SATA, PCI-E, or M.2? That is something a simple Google search will answer quite readily.

Comment: Meaning if I simply get a M.2 SSD, the read speed for a laptop will be not be faster with a PCIe SSD compatible slot, compared to other laptops with slots that can only handle a M.2 SSD?

Answer (score 1):

NO. PCI-e gen3x SSD is not an interface for "normal" SATA SSD drives. PCI-e SSD is essentially a PCI-e card with SSD technology built in.

So no, it will not make "any kind of SSD faster."

Answer (score -1):

PCI-E is faster since PCI-E has more bandwidth than the 6 Gbps speed of a SATA. PCI-E is usually used as slots for GPU's, so you need the bandwidth to send rendered, high quality graphics to the monitor. Just an analogy. In conclusion, PCIE is faster that SATA. In some cases.